# bind mouse enter event on browser elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How can I bind mouse enter/hover event on the "current browser tab" and the 
main "close button" of browser.Attaching images for reference.

[image: mouse hover on the current tab]

[image: mouse hover on the main close button]

Comment: This is not possible. Even if you're making a chrome extension I don't think you have access to it. Certainly not for a website.

Comment: I actually believe this is possible. But it would take some hacking. You have to use `event.clientY` to determine the mouse position relative to the top of the screen. Maybe if the absolute value of the difference is between 50 and 60, it will work

Comment: @RichardHamilton don't you mean `event.screenY`? - Nice thinking, but you'd need to assume you know the height of the tabbar (which you don't). Even then, you might as well use global focus/blur or the beforeUnload events.

Comment: You just can't detect it, it would be against broswer rules.

Comment: Thanks for the responses here. Not sure why someone down voted, I'd not have asked if I had known whether its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its not worth doing it, so will go with other options.